# Xamrin forms Charge a page before going to it

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamaring forms , I want to do 4 content pages. One will display my to do listand images.

I would like to know if there is a way to charge my todo list before going to the last page from any of my 3 pages.

Knowing that I am going through pages like this :

```
var page = new LastPage();
MainView.Content = page.Content;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Add a method in LastPage class and do the change you want in the method. Call this method to the page instance before setting the instance as content.

Comment: Do you mean Change? or Charge? Also do not replace the content of a single page, instead push the new page. Go through [Navigation fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/) and post if you have more questions. You might want to take a quick course on Forms fundamentals, [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oU10SXt2W58pu2L0v2dOW-1) is a great place to start

Comment: I mean to charger a content of a page before going to it @shanranm

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

If so, you need achieve it by MVVM and `INotifyPropertyChanged`

First of all, you should create a model to achieve the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
  public  class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        string name;
        public string Name
        {
            set
            {
                if (name != value)
                {
                    name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Image");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
        }

        string count;
        public string Count
        {
            set
            {
                if (count != value)
                {
                    count = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Count");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return count;
            }
        }

      

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Then you need the ViewModel to push the data.

```
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyModel> myModels { get; set; }
        public MyViewModel() {

            myModels = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Count = "0", Name = "test1" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Count = "1", Name = "test2" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Count = "2", Name = "test3" });
        }


    }
```

In the First page and end page, you should binding same viewmodel that use `bindingcontext` like following code format.
`MainPage.xaml`

```
  <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->

        <Button Text="Next" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
        <ListView x:Name="mylistview" ItemsSource="{Binding myModels}" HasUnevenRows="True" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell >

                        <StackLayout>
                           

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               FontSize="Large"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />
                               <Label Text="{Binding Count}"
                                 LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                               
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center"  />


                         
                        </StackLayout>


                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        MyViewModel viewModel;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel  = new MyViewModel();
            BindingContext = viewModel;
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(viewModel));
        }
    }
```

Here is my demo, you can download it.

https://github.com/851265601/XFormsMvvmChange

Here is a helpful article about it, you can refer to it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm